# What does it mean if, for a real input $x, x^T x$ is a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was trying to find a least squares solution using the normal equation. I created an 'input' vector $x$ with a fixed coefficient times $i$ plus a random number.

As far as I know, for a $x^T * x$ to be a singular matrix, the elements of $x$ must have some fixed relationship to each other (there probably is a term for that...).

That's why when creating $x$, I added a random offset. But $x^T * x$ is singular after all.

Could this just be bad luck, or is there something more to it I wasn't previously aware of?

Comment: Do you mean $x^T x$? What are the dimensions of $x$? If it is a column vector, then $x^T x$ is a scalar, and is never zero (assuming $x$ is real) unless $x = 0$. If $x$ is a row vector, then $x^T x$ is a square matrix with rank 1, hence always singular. If $x$ is something else, please specify.

Comment: Your question would benefit greatly from typesetting, because it's hard to understand an expression like x^T * x. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is $x$ a row or column vector?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just realized my mistake. I'm solving $\theta = (x^{T}x)^{-1} x^{T}y$ and for the two parameters that I have in $\theta$ I need two columns in x. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like $x$ is a row vector of the form
$$
x = [x_1\; x_2\; \cdots \; x_n]
$$
So that $x^Tx$ is a matrix of the form
$$
xx^T = \pmatrix{x_1^2 & x_1x_2 & \cdots & x_{1}x_n\\
x_1x_2 & x_2^2 &  \cdots      &  x_2x_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
x_1x_n & x_2x_n & \cdots  & x_n^2}
$$
This matrix is singular for $n\geq 2$, no matter what $x$ is. In particular, it is a symmetric (positive semidefinite) matrix of rank $1$.

Comment: a singular matrix couldn't be positive definite

Comment: @ebrahim fixed${}$

Comment: @Bungo good catch